# Magento 2, new widget with image chooser parameter, does not save picture

Tags: magento2

I am new on magento2.

I create a new widget and one of the parameters is a picture chooser, I just use this https://gist.github.com/cedricblondeau/6174911fb4bba6cb4943 code. Everthing looks well. I can open media folder and choose the picture I want to use.
When I choose the picture, the picture field on the form, is filled with this value: http://local.magento.com/admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvcHVycGxlLmpwZyJ9fQ,,/key/4c150d984998702b74709bb8f05820aff2f85a968d47e50f9638b7d2a7b1ced3/

But when I save the form widget data, the picture fied has this value:
{{media url=

nothing more. How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: The problem was on the configuration.
On Configuration > General > Content Management, "Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog"  It should be "yes"

Comment: not a solution as you are hard-coding the widget parameters and you will have problems moving to different envirourments